How to combine indicators of different timeframes
Can you tell me why an error occurs when  establish a coupling between indicators that operate on datas with different timeframes
class MyStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    params = dict(period=20)

    def __init__(self):

        # data0 is a daily data
        sma0 = btind.SMA(self.data, period=10)  # sma from the minutes
        # data1 is a weekly data
        sma1 = btind.SMA(self.data1, period=10)  # sma from the daily timeframe

        self.buysig = sma0 > sma1()  # minute sma greater than day sma1

    def next(self):
        if self.buysig[0]:
            print('daily sma is greater than weekly sma1')


datafile = "GAZP-1.csv"
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  
file_path = os.path.join(
    current_dir, "historical_data", datafile
) 
datafile1 = "GAZP-24.csv"
file_path1 = os.path.join(
    current_dir, "historical_data", datafile1
) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    # Create a cerebro entity
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro(runonce=True)
    cerebro.addstrategy(MyStrategy)
    data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData( 
        dataname=file_path, 
        separator="\t",  
        dtformat="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",  
        openinterest=-1, 
        fromdate=datetime(2023, 6, 10),
        todate=datetime(2024, 6, 28),
    )  
    data1 = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(  
        dataname=file_path1, 
        separator="\t",  
        dtformat="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",
        openinterest=-1, 
        fromdate=datetime(2023, 6, 10),
        todate=datetime(2024, 6, 28),
    )  

    cerebro.adddata(data)
    cerebro.adddata(data1)
    cerebro.broker.setcash(100000.0)
    print("Starting Portfolio Value: %.2f" % cerebro.broker.getvalue())
    cerebro.run()
    print("Final Portfolio Value: %.2f" % cerebro.broker.getvalue())

I get the following error

dst[i] = op(srca[i], srcb[i])
~~~~^^^
IndexError: array index out of range

I'm following the instructions https://www.backtrader.com/docu/concepts/#lines-delayed-indexing
explain my mistake, the most important thing is to understand the cause. Thank you
